# Exeption System.ArgumentNullException for parameter baseUri in Videos.Insert when uploading video via Youtube Data API

Tags: c#, video, youtube

Excuse me for newbie's question ...

I am developing an C# .NET application for uploading video files to my YouTube channel in background [C#, .NET Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10 x64, YouTube Data API v.3].

To upload method I used a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video) from Developer's Site.

I made a project, installed nuget package with YouTube API and obtained an OAUTH credentials from API console. I used exactly the sample code with minimum changes in parameters' values. And all worked well until yesterday. But now I see the following exception message at the console:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)... System.ArgumentNullException: Value can not be undefined. Parameter name: baseUri

NB: My console is Cyrillic, so I have translated some part of the message to English.

From call to call HTTP error code changes. It may be 400 (as above) or 403 (Forbidden).
Step by step I investigated all calls of API's methods and have found that exception occurs in Videos.Insert. I could not trace all the chain without source code, but I found an obsoleted version of ResumableUpload.cs at the GitHub but haven't reveal any idea about problem. It looks like baseUri should be obtained correctly.

Would You please explain me a problem or advise where to look forward ?

The full source code and full console output of my project is attached below

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: upload a video.
    /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
    /// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
    /// </summary>
    internal class UploadVideo
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
            Console.WriteLine("==============================");

            try
            {
                new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            ClientSecrets secret;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                secret = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
                    Console.WriteLine("----------- Secret: " + secret.ToString() + " OK");  // Debug message
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    secret,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }
                Console.WriteLine("----------- Credentials Recieved: " + credential.ToString() + " OK");  // Debug message
                Console.WriteLine("----------- Client ID: " + secret.ClientId.ToString() + " OK");  // Debug message

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
            });
            Console.WriteLine("----------- YT Service Name: " + youtubeService.Name);  // Debug message
            Console.WriteLine("----------- YT Service AppName: " + youtubeService.ApplicationName);  // Debug message
            Console.WriteLine("----------- YT Service BasePath: " + youtubeService.BasePath);  // Debug message
            Console.WriteLine("----------- YT Service BaseUri: " + youtubeService.BaseUri);  // Debug message
            Console.WriteLine("----------- YT Service BaseUri: " + youtubeService.HttpClient.ToString());  // Debug message

            Console.WriteLine("----------- HTTP Initialized: OK");  // Debug message

                string myDescription = "Session " + DateTime.Now.ToString();  // Generating pseudo-random description
            var video = new Video();
                Console.WriteLine("----------- Video created: " + video.ToString() + " OK");  // Debug message
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = myDescription;   //  Title added
            video.Snippet.Description = myDescription;  //  Description added
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "27"; 
                Console.WriteLine("----------- Snippet set: " + video.Snippet.Title + " OK");  // Debug message

            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"D:\Temp\_AAA\zoom_22.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.
                Console.WriteLine("----------- video.Status: " + video.Status.PrivacyStatus + " OK");  // Debug message


            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("----------- Filestream " + filePath + " is writeable: " + fileStream.CanWrite.ToString() + " OK");
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "status", fileStream, "video/*");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------- youtubeService Insert is launched: OK");  // Debug message

                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                Console.WriteLine("----------- Ready to launch async Upload: OK");  // Debug message
                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("----------- Async Upload is done: OK");  // Debug message
            }
        }

        void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
YouTube Data API: Upload Video
==============================
----------- Secret: Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets OK
----------- Credentials Recieved: Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential OK
----------- Client ID: 991553560147-p5e3tk39k5tn0nd0e4is4k3h2no9hhuk.apps.googleusercontent.com OK
----------- YT Service Name: youtube
----------- YT Service AppName: YT-Load1
----------- YT Service BasePath:
----------- YT Service BaseUri: https://www.googleapis.com/
----------- YT Service BaseUri: Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableHttpClient
----------- HTTP Initialized: OK
----------- Video created: Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video OK
----------- Snippet set: Session 22.07.2020 2:09:05 OK
----------- video.Status: unlisted OK
----------- Filestream D:\Temp\_AAA\zoom_22.mp4 is writeable: True OK
----------- youtubeService Insert is launched: OK
----------- Ready to launch async Upload: OK
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   in Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__83.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 378
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value can not be undefined.
Parameter's name: baseUri
   in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   in Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__87.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:строка 460
----------- Async Upload is done: OK
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Looking at the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3)  for Google YouTube API, it only supports .Net Framework 4.5+. If you can, upgrade the .NET version, otherwise you'll have to find a compatible version of the YouTube SDK

Comment: @Glynn-Hurrel  Thank You. It seems that was a cover problem. I'd changed to .NET 4.5 and see extended exception message about quota limit (the root problem) :-)